# HttpURLConnection is making multiple requests...any idea

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, httpurlconnection

I am using the below code, which makes multiple POST requests for some users even if it is  coded only for one request, and for me it works good and getresponseCode return 200 and for some others it gives null pointer exception on getresponseCode.

```
URL url = new URL(strURL);          
lobjConn = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`enter code here`
lobjConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "mysession="+smCookie);
lobjConn.setDoInput(true);
lobjConn.setDoOutput(true);
lobjConn.setUseCaches(false);
lobjConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
lobjConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
lobjConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
lobjOS = new DataOutputStream(lobjConn.getOutputStream());
int rc = lobjConn.getResponseCode();
```

when the execution reaches the above last line it throws NPE and when we check the log on server, it's showing 2 request reach server, even if we are not in any loop.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:719) at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:646) at
COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.‌​java:411) at
COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.‌​java:703) at
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:399) at
WBDocSubmitOffline.getObjectId(WBDocSubmitOffline.java:240) at
WBDocSubmitOffline.NotesMain(WBDocSubmitOffline.java:98) at
lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us the NPE detail please.

Comment: Hi Friend, the lobjConn is not null as I checked it by debugging. the getresponsecode() is actually after few lines of data writing by lobjOS , but I put it here for the brevity of sample code. by the way it's already a method-local-variable.Is there any way I can block to nullifying that variable Regards JG

Comment: Hi Friends, below is my NPE

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:719)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:646)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:411)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:703)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:399)
at WBDocSubmitOffline.getObjectId(WBDocSubmitOffline.java:240)
at WBDocSubmitOffline.NotesMain(WBDocSubmitOffline.java:98)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

It's pointless getting the response code before you've sent anything. You're supposed to send the request first, then get the response code, then get the response if required. The code as written doesn't make sense.